Add a custom class on Woocommerce orders list table
I want to add a custom styling on Orders List table for specific rows, based on a meta data value. My code works perfectly on the Legacy option of Order data storage. However, with the HPOS enabled, the filter is not triggered at all. Is there any similar filter that can be used, or the only way is to use jQuery and call the API for every row to get that info?
function addCssClassToOrderListRow($classes, $class, $post_id)
{
    if ('shop_order' === OrderUtil::get_order_type( $post_id ) && is_admin()) {
        $order = wc_get_order($post_id);

        $meta_value = $order->get_meta('my_meta_key', true);

        if (!empty($meta_value)) {
            // Add a custom class
            $classes[] = 'custom_class';
        }
    }

    return $classes;
    
}
add_filter('post_class', 'addCssClassToOrderListRow', 10, 3);


You can use the woocommerce_shop_order_list_table_order_css_classes hook like this
function addCssClassToOrderListRow($classes, $order){
    $meta_value = $order->get_meta('my_meta_key', true);

    if (!empty($meta_value)) {
        // Add a custom class
        $classes[] = 'custom_class';
    }

    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_list_table_order_css_classes', 'addCssClassToOrderListRow', 10, 2 );

